# Get color from string (hash)

Tags: c#, wpf

How do I calculate a random color, thats going to be more or less unique to a specific string?
Its true that RGB format of (0-255, 0-255, 0-255) will only allow maximum of 16581375 unique colors, while strings are indefinite.

The string can be random like `hello123` or `bye456`.

My goal is to show a control (expander) in a almost unique color by text of the header.
Because on other list in GUI there is a reference to that expander, so i want to help the user to find that entry quicker.

So I need to get a `SolidColorBrush` for background.

Example:
The header of one expander is `hello123` and the following expander header is `bye456`. So I want to set the background of each header to a (nearly) unique color.

Answer (score 2):

Could do something like this to get your color code

```
"#" + Convert.ToString("hello123".GetHashCode(), 16)
```

`"hello123"` returns `#12c09349`

Comment: I tried this, but if the string is similar, its the same color.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the background of your controls that uses SolidColorBrush like this:

```
using System.Windows.Media;

new SolidColorBrush((Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#FFDFD991"));
```

Comment: I have edited the question, because the input string is a random string like hello123 and bye456.

Comment: What do you mean? Can you post exactly what you want? The objects and values that you are trying to use would be helpful.

Comment: I have self answered the question, dont understand why its been dow voted. Found no duplicate. Hope, now you understand the question.

Comment: It still unclear what is this string hash that you are trying to convert in color. Your question is too simple, without datails, probably that's why ppl downvoted it.

Comment: The string can be everythink like hello123... I convert a hash of it and of this hash a color and of the color a solidcolorbrush :)

Comment: How are you supposed to extract a color has from a string like this? It makes no sense.

Comment: What I assume he means is to calculate a random color, thats going to be more or less unique to a specific string, and he is looking for an algorithm for that. While it is possible, one has to bear in mind that RGB format of (0-255, 0-255, 0-255) will only allow maximum of 16581375 unique colors, while strings are indefinite.

Still, I cannot see a point where one would need this, and OP needs to update his question with details.

Comment: Thats right Kamil. Thanks, I have edited the question.

Answer (score -3):

With this method you get a SolidColorBrush which can be used as Background:

```
private static SolidColorBrush GetSolidColorBrushFromString(string value)
{
   // Get Color from string
   var md5 = MD5.Create();
   var hash = md5.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(value));
   var color = Color.FromRgb(hash[0], hash[1], hash[2]);
   var brush = new SolidColorBrush(color);
   brush.Opacity = 0.2; // Readability in UI
   return brush;
}
```

Usage:

```
var brushBackground = GetSolidColorBrushFromString(expander.Name);
expander.Background = brushBackground;
```